# What the bollocks does this mean?

Tags: discussion

I got a big red banner at the top of WPSE saying this:

```
WordPress requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.
```

What is it implying?

Comment: That message would seem to imply that this site is running WordPress, but I'm certain it's not. Are you sure that's the exact message you see?

Comment: Indeed I am. I copy-pasta'd the error message. It seems to come when I post a link to a jQuery file, so I would assume it is some sort of protection against hackers trying to run external scripts on the site.

Comment: And you see that message on this site (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how clearer that message can be...

For this website to work fully it loads JavaScript files, some of which are loaded from different domains (CDN's).

You will get this message if your browser is blocking these JavaScript files or for whatever reason they didn't load...

Comment: Fair enough, I just wasn't sure if it was a bug or not. How would I find out if that is the case (running Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

I'll get that every now and then too...usually when I come back again later it's fixed, it's just an error connecting to an external server that's preventing the download of javascript files key to the operation of the site.